# GridFS in Laravel 5.4 doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4

I'm using PHP7, Laravel 5.4 and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb (PECL package). I need to use GridFS, that it's included into the MongoDB PECL package, so I'm trying to get GridFS like this:

```
$gridfs = DB::connection('mongo')->getMongoDB()->getGridFS();
```

But it's throwing the exception: "Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::getGridFS()".
Any idea of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using `mongo-php-library 2.2` driver, **getGridFS()** method no longer exists, however you can use `Bucket` class for upload and download documents to mongodb grid. You can try the following:

```
//upload file
$bucket = \DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$resource = fopen($file_path, "a+");
$file_id = $bucket->uploadFromStream($file_path, $resource);

//download file
$bucket = \DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->selectGridFSBucket();
$file_metadata = $bucket->findOne(["_id" => $file_id]);
$path = $file_metadata->filename;

if(!file_exists($path)) {
    $downloadStream = $bucket->openDownloadStream($file_id);
    $stream = stream_get_contents($downloadStream, -1);
    $ifp = fopen($path, "a+");
    fwrite($ifp, $stream);
    fclose($ifp);
}
```

Note that `$file_id` variable is an ObjectId, if you have an string value, you need to convert to ObjectId: `$file_id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($str_file_id);`